# How can I implement music sharing to Instagram story in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, instagram, share, instagram-api

I am building a music streaming mobile app like Spotify in Flutter. One of the functionalities I would like to implement is so the user can share a music video to Instagram story. My question is how would you go about this / is this possible to implement in Flutter. I have pasted a photo of how Spotify implements this for reference. Any help would be very appreciated :)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUg8w.jpg)

I have looked into Meta's Developers for info(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories/) but there are only instructions for Swift and Kotlin.

Comment: Does this package solves your problem? https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus

You can use .shareFiles() method to share the music video using platform sharing platforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you can use the `share_plus` package.

1. Add `share_plus: ^4.0.0` to your pubspec.yaml dependencies
2. `import 'package:share_plus/share_plus.dart';`
3. `Share.shareXFiles([pickedImage], text: 'Great picture');`

Note that `pickedImage` is an XFile. You can have a user choose an xFile from their local file system or gallery using the `image_picker` package.

Full example on how to use `image_picker` with `share_plus`

```
class ImageHandler extends StatefulWidget {
  const ImageHandler({super.key});

  @override
  State<ImageHandler> createState() => _ImageHandlerState();
}

class _ImageHandlerState extends State<ImageHandler> {
  var _image; // type File
  var pickedImage; // type XFile (needed for sharing)

  var imageButtonText = "Choose an image from Gallery";

  /// Get from gallery
  _getFromGallery() async {
    final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
    pickedImage = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    // Pick an image
    setState(() {
      if (pickedImage != null) {
        _image = File(pickedImage.path);
        imageButtonText = "Replace";
      }
    });
  }

  _shareImage() async {
    Share.shareXFiles([pickedImage], text: 'Great picture');
  }
```

Although I've never tried it, `image_picker` should work with videos as well. Docs are [here](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker)

This should work just like how spotify does it in the example you gave.